# Why does my transistor explode in a simulator?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, npn, common-emitter

I'm new to electronics and I can't identify the reason why my transistor explodes when I simulate it.

I am simulating a simple common emitter amplifier with a power supply of 12 volts.

[image]

Comment: Try to connect GND to B1 12V voltage source. Also, reduce the input signal amplitude to 50mV.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's not exploding anymore although the output voltage is not what is required.

Comment: Your operating point is poorly chosen. Q1 is saturated as mentioned by Spehro Pefhany.

Comment: I have only watched youtube tutorials for the biasing and I am not quite familiar with how the operating point can be chosen properly.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the open power supply, your biasing is poorly designed, Q1 will saturate.